# D3 js - Add a label or text to drag and drop circles

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I used this [tutorial](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e) to create a set of circles, line them up by a read in attribute, color code them, and have them be movable (drag and drop). I get that I need to create a 'node' and append 'circle' and 'text' to each node, but I can't get it all to work together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Set Lineups</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {padding: 15px}
        .active {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
        text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            pointer-events: none;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<!--begin svg block-->
    <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
    <script>
    //now in js

    //define variables
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        radius = 32;

    // setup x
    var xValue = function(d) {
        if (d.Side == "Starboard") {return x=Math.round(2*radius)}
            else if (d.Side == "BiStar") {return x=Math.round(2*radius)}
            else if (d.Side == "Port") {return x=Math.round(5*radius)}
            else if (d.Side == "BiPort") {return x=Math.round(5*radius)}
            else if (d.Side == "Cox") {return x=Math.round(8*radius)}
    }

    // setup y
    var yPort = 0
    var yStar = 0
    var yCox = 0
    var yValue = function(d) {
        if (d.Side == "Starboard") {
            y = Math.round(2*radius) + yStar;
            yStar = y;
            return y}
            else if (d.Side == "BiStar") {
                y = Math.round(2*radius) + yStar;
                yStar = y;
                return y}
            else if (d.Side == "Port") {
                y = Math.round(2*radius) + yPort;
                yPort = y;
                return y}
            else if (d.Side == "BiPort") {
                y = Math.round(2*radius) + yPort;
                yPort = y;
                return y}
            else if (d.Side == "Cox") {
                y = Math.round(2*radius) + yCox;
                yCox = y;
                return y}
    }

    //read in the data
    d3.csv("Roster.csv", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            name : d["Full Name"];
            side : d["Side"];
            injured : d["Injured"];
            absent : d["Absent"];
            console.log(d);
        });

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(data)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));

        node.append("circle")
            .style("fill", function(dg, i) { 
                if (dg.Side == "Port") {color = "red"}
                    else if (dg.Side == "Starboard") {color = "green"}
                    else if (dg.Side == "BiPort") {color = "orange"}
                    else if (dg.Side == "BiStar") {color = "blue"}
                    else if (dg.Side == "Cox") {color = "grey"}
                if (dg.Injured == "Yes") {color = "yellow"}
                if (dg.Absent == "Yes") {color = "yellow"}
                return color;
            })
            .attr("cx", function(dg) { return xValue(dg); })
            .attr("cy", function(dg) { return yValue(dg); })

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("cx", function(dg) { return xValue(dg); })
            .attr("cy", function(dg) { return yValue(dg); })
            .text(function(dg) {return dg['Full Name']});


        function dragstarted(dg) {
          d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
        }

        function dragged(dg) {
          d3.select(this).attr("cx", dg.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", dg.y = d3.event.y);
        }

        function dragended(dg) {
          d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
        }

    })
</script>
</body>
```

Here is snapshot of the data:

Full Name   Side        Injured Absent

Name0       Port        No      No

Name1       Starboard   No      No

Name2       Starboard   No      Yes

Name 2      BiPort      No      No

Name3       BiStar      No      No

Name4       Starboard   Yes     No

Name5       Cox         No      No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right approach, but it'll be easier if you assign a transform to the node (or `g` element) so that text and circles align by default, and I'll take that approach in this answer *(though you could re-calculate the movement of the nodes and recalculate the text and circle coordinates individually too)*.

Central to why you may be experiencing difficulty, you'll see that in the drag functions you are setting attributes `cx` and `cy`:

```
d3.select(this).attr("cx", dg.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", dg.y = d3.event.y);
```

But a dragged `g`/node element does not have those properties - and these are the `this` which that line references. This is because you've moved the on drag functions to the nodes when they were originally appended to the circles.

Instead, replace the above line with one that can recalculate the transform for the dragged `g`/node. This will update both text and circle within a dragged `g`/node (and any other children too).

Of course if using a transform for each `g`/node, you don't need to use the `cx`,`cy` properties of the circles at all.

Together it would look something like this:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 32;

var circles = d3.range(20).map(function() {
  return {
    x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius),
    y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius)
  };
});

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(d3.schemeCategory20);
    
var circleGroup = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(circles)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr('transform',function(d) { return 'translate('+d.x+','+d.y+')'; })
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

circleGroup.append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })

circleGroup.append("text")
   .text(function(d,i) { return i; })
   .style('text-anchor','middle')
   .attr('y',4);


function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate("+(d.x = d3.event.x)+','+(d.y = d3.event.y)+')' );
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks man! This was super helpful. My understanding of 'transform' was definitely not complete. Did some further googling and this helped fill the gaps for me (https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js).

Comment: So I got everything to work, except the circles don't initialize where I want them to. Throws an error that the items to be transformed initially are undefined. But once I try to drag the objects, the transform works well.

I checked the inspector and the each <g> object does have the proper x and y stored with it, but it still isn't initialized there.
<g x="64" y="256" transform="translate(undefined,undefined)"

Thoughts?

Comment: OOOOH WAIT. YOU INITIALIZE UNDER THE FIRST TRANSFORM FOR CIRCLEGROUP...

.attr('transform',function(d) { return 'translate('+xValue(d)+','+yValue(d)+')'; })